# problem with sending async data to UIPickerViewDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to send use some data that's received asynchronously from a file download and some parsing,

```
func getMachineName(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void ) {
    let machineNumberData = self.advertData[CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey]
    if machineNumberData != nil {
        if let data = machineNumberData as? Data {
            // use `data` for the bytes
            let hexData = data.hexEncodedString()
            // range
            let number = String(hexData[hexData.index(hexData.startIndex, offsetBy: 12)...hexData.index(hexData.startIndex, offsetBy: 15)])
            let machineNumberHex =  machineNumberHexToDecimal(machineNumberHex: number)
            getMachineNameFromMachineNumber(machineNumber: machineNumberHex) { (machineName) in
                print("machine name from main: \(machineName)")
                completion(machineName)
            }
        } else {
            NSLog("Error parsing Machine number")
        }
    }
}
```

I then get the data from the closure and try to pass it to the pickerView

```
private func _pv(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String {
    
    let dev = self.pickerDevices[row]
    let id = dev.internalUUID
    guard let name = dev.name
    else {
        return "\(id)"
    }
    dev.adData.getMachineName { (mName) in
        print("machine name from wbmanager: \(mName)")
        // Problem -> Unexpected non-void return value in void function
         return "\(mName)"
    }
    
    // Problem -> Cannot find 'mName' in scope
    return "\(name) \(mName)"
}

 public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return self._pv(pickerView, titleForRow: row, forComponent: component)
}
```

However I can not access the data outside of the closure to send it to pickerview.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You cannot return a value from the asynchronous closure to the UI thread directly. What you could do however is to load the data and bind that data to the picker view after it loads, while showing some sort of activity indicator on the UI.

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate a bit more, can you provide a small example please

Comment: Essentially, in your VC, when the view loads, you could create a dispatch group, call the API that downloads the file for each of the row items. Until such time the group of API calls complete, show an activity indicator.